# Call lightbox from javascript function

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I have a webpage with the following code:

```
<script>
$("button").click(function(){
  var loc = window.location.href;
  $.post("../cgi-bin/test.py", 
  {stuff_for_python: loc},

  function myFunction(data) {
    window.open("/img/" + data);
  });
});
</script>
```

When clicked, the button sends the current URL as a variable to a python script, which then formats it and queries a MySQL database to get the name an image file that is paired with this unique URL. The image name is then sent back to the page, where it is opened for viewing.

All the pieces are working together and the image is displaying correctly. What I would like to do now is to open the image in Lightbox (or a similar product). Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Example using http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var loc = window.location.href;
  $.post("../cgi-bin/test.py", 
  {stuff_for_python: loc},

  function myFunction(data) {
    $.colorbox({html:"<img src=\"/img/" + data + "\" />"});
  });
});
```

Or this maybe work better (sorry, I have not used colorbox in a while):

```
    $.colorbox({href:"/img/" + data});
```

Comment: The second solution did not work. The colorbox window opens up, but there's no picture displayed--just weird symbols. Your first solution worked, with one problem. The first time you click on the button, a tiny colorbox window opens with an "x". If you click on the x and then hit the button again, it displays correctly. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I figured out the problem--I had to manually add the height and width to the colorbox function. Things are all good now.